# Interpretation for the divergence of the force density function, relativistic waves

Tags: electromagnetism, waves

While studying E&M, I came across the force density for the electromagnetic field $\textbf f$. The following is the expression for the same
$$\textbf f = -\frac{1}{2}\nabla\left(\epsilon_0E^2+\frac{1}{\mu_0}B^2\right) - \epsilon_0\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(E\times B)$$
If we express it in terms of the energy density of the fields $u$ and the Poynting vector $S$, it becomes
$$\textbf f = -\nabla u - \epsilon_0\mu_0 S$$
Here, I was wondering what the interpretation for the divergence of a "force density" function would be since if we take the divergence, we get
$$\nabla\cdot\textbf f = \left(\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} - \nabla^2\right)u$$
We see that the divergence of the force density is of the form of a relativistic wave equation and I have been trying to think of this for a while. The only case I was able to make sense of is if $\nabla\cdot \textbf f = 0\implies \textbf f = \nabla\times\Gamma$ for some function $\Gamma$ and the energy density behaves like a wave.

I tried looking around but did not find anything about this topic.
Thank You.